# Displaying an individual student's mark

Tags: java, arrays

I have to make a program that gathers the total number of assignments and the students mark for each assignment. The program returns each student's mark for the assignments. This is my output window right now:

> How many students are in the class? 2  *User input = assignmentLimit*
>
> How many assignments did you assign? 2  *User input = studentLimit*
>
> Assigment 1 marks:
>
> Student 1: 41 *User input*
>
> Student 2: 52 *User input*
>
> Assigment 2 marks:
>
> Student 1: 74 *User input*
>
> Student 2: 85 *User input*
>
> Student 1 marks
>
> 41.0
>
> 52.0
>
> Student 2 marks
>
> 74.0
>
> 85.0

But under the student 1 marks section, I want it to display 41.0 and 74.0. For Student 2 marks, I want to display 52.0 and 85.0. How would I do this? This is section that gathers and displays the marks:

```
double[][] mark = new double[assignmentLimit][studentLimit];
    for (index = 0; index < assignmentLimit; index++)
    {
        System.out.println("\nAssigment " + (index + 1) + " marks:");
        for (int studentMark = 0; studentMark < studentLimit; studentMark++)
        {
            System.out.print("\nStudent " + (studentMark + 1) + ": ");
            mark[index][studentMark] = Integer.parseInt(console.readLine());
        } // end of for(int index = 0; index < ARRAY_LIMIT; index++)
    }

    for (index = 0; index < studentLimit; index++)
    {  
        System.out.println("\nStudent " + (index + 1) + " marks");
        for (int studentMark = 0; studentMark < assignmentLimit; studentMark++)
        {
            System.out.println("\t" + mark[index][studentMark]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Read about _format specifiers_ in the manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
double[][] mark = new double[assignmentLimit][studentLimit];
    for (index = 0; index < assignmentLimit; index++)
    {
        System.out.println("\nAssigment " + (index + 1) + " marks:");
        for (int studentMark = 0; studentMark < studentLimit; studentMark++)
        {
            System.out.print("\nStudent " + (studentMark + 1) + ": ");
            mark[index][studentMark] = Integer.parseInt(console.readLine());
        } // end of for(int index = 0; index < ARRAY_LIMIT; index++)
    }

    for (index = 0; index < studentLimit; index++)
    {  
        System.out.println("\nStudent " + (index + 1) + " marks");
        for (int studentMark = 0; studentMark < assignmentLimit; studentMark++)
        {
            System.out.println("\t" + mark[studentMark][index]); // mark[studentMark][index] but not mark[index][studentMark]
        }
    }
```

Comment: It works! Can you please tell me why the studentMark and index had to be reversed? Thanks!

Comment: In your first nested for loops, you set marks of Assigment 1 and Assigment 2 to mark array, it means the first index (mark[first index][second index]) of mark array is index of assignments, and the second one is index of students; And in your second nested for loops, the first index in for loop is index of students，and second one is index of assignments, so index had to be reversed...I hope you could understand what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CWH_05_TakingInput {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Student Marks Input

        System.out.println("Enter a Hindi Marks");
        int hindi = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter a English Marks");
        int english = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter a Math Marks");
        int math = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter a Physics Marks");
        int physics = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter a Biology Marks");
        int biology = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter a Chemistry Marks");
        int chemistry = sc.nextInt();

        //Total Subject Calculation

        int total = hindi+english+math+physics+biology+chemistry;

        //Function

        System.out.println("Hindi : " +hindi);
        System.out.println("English : " +english);
        System.out.println("Math : " +math);
        System.out.println("Physics : " +physics);
        System.out.println("Biology : " +biology);
        System.out.println("Chemistry : " +chemistry);

        System.out.println("Your Total Marks = "+total);

      int percentage = (total/6);

      System.out.println("The Percentage is = "+percentage+"%");

// Function for Pass or Fail

      if (hindi>40 && english>40){
          System.out.println("Pass");
      }
      else if (math>40 && physics>40) {
          System.out.println("Pass");

      } else if (biology>40 && chemistry>40) {
          System.out.println("Pass");

      }
      else {
          System.out.println("Fail");
      }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).